# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns path with repeated directory name

Tags: php, apache, document-root

I am seeing a strange behavior when accessing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` on a subdomain. It contains a duplicate folder name which does not exist.

Here is the the relevant output of `$_SERVER`:

```
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/sub.domainname.com/sub.domainname.com
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/sub.domainname.com/index.php
```

It should be:

```
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/sub.domainname.com
```

Here is the virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName sub.domainname.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.domainname.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/sub.domainname.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's why you should define a constant like `ROOT` and rely on that one, rather than `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: Anyone care to explain their down-votes?

Comment: I don't get why this question gets downvoted. They probably do that just for fun. +1 for the question

Comment: @Scorpion where should this constant be defined?

Comment: You can define that in `index.php` like `define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__))`

Comment: I don't see any reason why this variable is considered *not reliable*. Of course there are workarounds but I'm interested in the reason for the wrong path. Can you paste your virtual host configuration for the subdomain? (+1)

Comment: @DanFromGermany How don't you see? If you can see it right here

Comment: @Scorpion but why is that? I've never come to the situation where DOCUMENT_ROOT was wrong. Neither with nginx, nor with Apache or any other server I had under administration.

Comment: @DanFromGermany i was thinking the same thing. It's fairly common to rely on variables such as this one for auto-discovery. In fact it's pretty necessary to allow us to build easily portable base code. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is perfectly reliable as long as you have set the webserver up correctly (and if you haven't, patching in a ROOT constant is just lazy, fix the issue!)

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have added the vhost config to my question.

Comment: check for .htaccess files also - a wrong document root is (as indicated by the answer below) a webserver config problem.

Comment: @Lee sometimes webserver control is not ours (ie. working on a client's server), so the reliability can not always be assumed.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is likely caused by a mis-configured webserver, the PHP documentation says this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contains the script directory as defined in the servers config file. Which may therefore be different to the actual script directory location.

> ***DOCUMENT_ROOT***
>   The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

Source: [PHP Reserved Variables `$_SERVER[]` Manual Page](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)